# How to remove sessions in tomcat jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I want to remove all session variables when I shutdown tomcat. Currently if I set a session variable value I am able to get its value even after restarting the tomcat. I even tried disabling persistent sessions in tomcat but get the same results. What to do?

Comment: How do u make sure that session variables are not getting set by code/config when u start tomcat?

Comment: What I do is in the first jsp file I run after restarting the tomcat I check the values of session variables but instead of showing null it gives me previous values.

Answer (score 2):

Just Edit your context.xml as below.

```
<Context>
  <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
  <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
  <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
  <Manager pathname="" />
</Context>
```

Knowledge is inside comment. :D

Comment: catalina.xml or context.xml?

Comment: context.xml sorry dude my bad.. :(

Comment: Remove all contents of work and temp directory. That should work.